# What is a "packed" structure in C?

Tags: c, microcontroller, packed

I am going though some C code written for the Microchip C30 compiler and I often see structs defined as follows:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__)) 
{
    IP_ADDR     MyIPAddr;               // IP address
    IP_ADDR     MyMask;                 // Subnet mask
    IP_ADDR     MyGateway;              // Default Gateway
        // etc...
} APP_CONFIG;
```

What does packed mean?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

When structures are defined, the compiler is allowed to add paddings (spaces without actual data) so that members fall in address boundaries that are easier to access for the CPU.

For example, on a 32-bit CPU, 32-bit members should start at addresses that are multiple of 4 bytes in order to be efficiently accessed (read and written). The following structure definition adds a 16-bit padding between both members, so that the second member falls in a proper address boundary:

```
struct S {
    int16_t member1;
    int32_t member2;
};
```

The structure in memory of the above structure in a 32-bit architecture is (**~** = padding):

```
+---------+---------+
| m1 |~~~~|   m2    |
+---------+---------+
```

When a structure is packed, these paddings are not inserted. The compiler has to generate more code (which runs slower) to extract the non-aligned data members, and also to write to them.

The same structure, when packed, will appear in memory as something like:

```
+---------+---------+
| m1 |   m2    |~~~~
+---------+---------+
```

Comment: Tangential question but why would one create a packed structure if it makes things slower? Is it to reduce memory footprint?

Comment: One use case: they are used very often for defining and implementing network protocols, binary formats... You usually don't want to add paddings to structures that are going to be stored or sent over the network.

Comment: Considering your example, 16 bits + 32 bits = 48 bits = 12 bytes and that is indeed a multiple of 4 bytes. Why would a compiler then apply padding?

Comment: @Maxitj, 48 bits are 6 bytes, not 12.

Comment: @Juliano silly me, was rly tired while I was reading this post :)

Comment: For some processors (such as x86), no additional object code is required for non-aligned access.  But it's still likely to execute more slowly, as the processor's microcode does the extra operations instead.

Answer (score 8):

It instructs the compiler to not add any padding between members of the `struct`.

See, for example, [this page](https://sites.google.com/site/eganya/Home/links/gcc---packed-structures).

Comment: I guess you mean the opposite - packed means to omit any padding and not to add it.

Comment: The link in this answer is broken, any chance of fixing?

Comment: Detail: "not add any padding between members" is more like to add _minimum_ packing.  Certain architectures may still oblige some padding in select cases.  (e.g. `int` must be on even address boundary to prevent bus fault.)

Answer (score 7):

Let me explain the concept of padding in structures and 
then packed structures by taking an example.

And then let us see why packing is required.

**Padding:**

```
struct eg_struct
{
           unsigned char abc;
           unsigned int  xyz;
}
```

When the structure is declared as above on a 16 bit architecture, the variable `abc` would be assigned some address. The next address is not assigned to variable `xyz`, instead one extra byte is added, and then the next address would be assigned to the variable `xyz`.

In the end, the structure looks something like below:

```
struct eg_struct
{
           unsigned char abc;
           unsigned char paddedbytes[1];
           unsigned int  xyz;
}
```

Padding makes addresses of member variables easily accessible to the microcontroller.
The disadvantage is extra unnecessary bytes that come into the picture.

**Packing:**

If same structure is declared using the attribute “`packed`”, the extra byte will not be added after the variable `abc`.

**Let me give one example where packing is needed:**

Consider a microcontroller interfaced with an EEPROM where some structure is being stored.

Imagine a function writing to the EEPROM would look as below:

```
Write_EEPROM(EEPROM address, Ram address, Byte count);
```

Now if packing is not done, the extra padded bytes would occupy space in the EEPROM, which is of no use.

Comment: @laurenz albe Thanks for making my answer more presentable.

Answer (score 2):

One thing that has not been explicitly called out is that packing usually is done to match predefined field structures. For example, at the low level layer of a network interface, a series of bytes is exchanged between networked machines. After the data is received, it will need to be mapped to a high level structure so that the data can be manipulated easily. This is when no-padding is usually necessary, so that the structure directly maps to the bytes.

Network data interchange also involves byte endianness issue (i.e. almost all network data uses big endian format regardless the endianness of the source and destination machines).

Furthermore, some machines **cannot** access wide data in non-aligned address, for example, Cortex-M0 cores cannot access 32-bit data in non-32-bit aligned address, so care must be taken on writing networking code in such cases.

Answer (score 1):

`_attribute__((__packed__))` means (most probably) "do not insert any padding to make things faster" and may also mean "do not insert any alignments to preserve alignment".

Answer (score 1):

When packed used during structure declaration, compiler will not add any padding to the members of the same structure. Below is the example code and output which is self explanatory.

```
$ cat structure_packed.c
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct __attribute__((__packed__))
{
        char a;
        int ai;
        char ac;
}A;

struct B
{
        char b;
        int bi;
        char bc;
};

int main()
{
         A a;
        struct B b;
        int c;
        printf("size of struct A: %lu, addr a: %p, addr ai: %p, addr ac: %p\n", sizeof(a), &(a.a), &(a.ai), &a.ac);
        printf("size of struct B: %lu, addr b: %p, addr bi: %p, addr bc: %p\n", sizeof(b), &(b.b), &(b.bi), &b.bc);
        printf("addr of c: %p\n", &c);
        return 0;
}
```

**Compile**

```
$ gcc structure_packed.c -o structure_packed
```

**Run|Output**

> ```
> $ ./structure_packed
> size of struct A: 6, addr a: 0x7ffc6f177ed6, addr ai: 0x7ffc6f177ed7, addr ac: 0x7ffc6f177edb
> size of struct B: 12, addr b: 0x7ffc6f177edc, addr bi: 0x7ffc6f177ee0, addr bc: 0x7ffc6f177ee4
> addr of c: 0x7ffc6f177ed0
> ```

Answer (score 0):

> why would one create a packed structure if it makes things slower?

Because in addition to reducing the memory footprint, when the structure is manually packed from its largest to its smallest members, all memory access usually ends up being at an even-aligned memory address, which on some microprocessors significantly increases performance.

Some microprocessors cannot access memory larger than a byte at an odd memory address and will incur a trap, causing the code to crash.

Some microprocessors suffer severe penalties when accessing memory larger than a byte at an odd address, needing more code, invalidating the cach(es), or both.

See Eric S. Raymond's excellent "The Lost Art of Structure Packing":

http://www.catb.org/esr/structure-packing/

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34998407)

Comment: I would be interested to know how my answer does not answer "why would one create a packed structure if it makes things slower?" - thank you.

Comment: The question is "what is a packed structure?"  This is an answer to a completely different question.

Comment: It seems to be a reply to damned's comment on [Juliano's answer](/a/5473235/4850040), and only tangentially related to the question.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I recommend you delete this answer from here (where it doesn't belong).  You can [ask and answer](/questions/ask) the question, "_Why would one create a packed structure if it makes things slower?_" if it has not already been asked here on SO.

Comment: Your recommendation makes no sense to me: I answered a subsequent ensuing question, with an answer which I consider relevant. Not only that, but the link which I provided is relevant to the larger "what is a packed structure?" question in general.

Prompted by your feedback, I have decided not to invest any more time and effort into this matter.