# Writing a struct to a buffer

Tags: c, serialization, struct, buffer

I am trying to understand the process by which I can serialize and de-serialize data in C. I wrote code that I believe should write a simple struct to a char buffer.

```
#include <packet.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdint.h>


typedef struct
{
        int A;
        int B;
        int C;
}test_packet;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
        test_packet p;
        p.A = 1;
        p.B = 2;
        p.C = 3;

        char buffer [sizeof(p)];
        memcpy(buffer, &p, sizeof(p));
        printf("%x \n", buffer);

        return 0;
}
```

However, when I run this code, since the struct being serialized is statically coded, I expect to see a buffer that's the same each time. I don't, I see a buffer that appears to be full of random data:

```
./SerializePacket
41bf5380
./SerializePacket
d89fc790
./SerializePacket
aea2c00
./SerializePacket
d355dc10
```

Can anyone alleviate me of my ignorance here?

Comment: You're printing the address of the buffer

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was something dumb like that. Can you point me in the right direction on printing the arrays contents instead of its address?

--Nevermind, I got it, thanks

Comment: @KevinJohn JUst do something like `        for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(buffer); ++i) {

            printf("%x", buffer[i]);

        }` ...?

Comment: For serialize, maybe you need a protocol.  For example: `JSON`, or just  `TLV(type-length-value)`.

Answer (score 0):

What you are printing is a pointer, the address of the buffer.

About serialization: you are copying the struct over the buffer, **with padding and all**. That it's not portable, unless you serialize and de-serialize in the same computer. To serialize a struct directly copying to the buffer, you should use packed structures (see: [What is a "packed" structure in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5473189/9987237), https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment). Also, using an integer of fixed size is preferred for serialized data, for example, `uint16_t` for a 16 bits unsigned integer.

Comment: "...unless you serialize / deserialize it on the same computer with both the code writing and the code reading having been compiled by exaclty the same compiler in the same version..."

Comment: Also, speaking of portability: Mind the endianness of your serialized data. *Don't use packed structures unless they conain octets only*  - they are not portable as their members' endianness will differ on different architectures.