# How to make an if statements that runs in each condition a .c file (a full source code)

Tags: c

i got no code or anything but an idea bumped up in my head . I have those 4 source codes a completed scripted files . i want to connect them with a 5th file with an if statement that if the user choices a number it's gonna excute an exact .c file .
Exemple **(not a real source code)**

```
scanf("%d",&x)
if (x==1)
excute system1.c
if (x==2)
excute system2.c
```

etc etc any help please . i don't want to put the whole codes in the same file it's pain

Comment: Normally you don't "execute a c file", instead you call a function that is defined in that c file.

Comment: C code isn't a script. You can execute programs. You can compile C code. You could, in theory, automate compiling and executing C code, but that's not recommended unless you have some very unusual requirements.

Comment: I was commenting on your question, not the code.

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to include an example "more real". What are, in your example, system1.c and system2.c? Actual source files or executable files obtained after compiling them? In the first case whay you ask is some sort of dynamic inclusion that in C (that is not a scripting language) is not possible. In the latter case you could execute it through functions such as `system ()`, `popen`, `exec` and so on.

Comment: You just had to google `system + C`.... Try [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5473235/11336762)

Comment: What kind of help are you looking for? It is a function and it tells how to call it. I'll try a disperate last attempt: 1) you compile your program program1.c (it needs to have a main) - 2) you get an executable program1.exe - 3) you call `system (program1)`. Easy!

Comment: Do not vandalize the question, even though it's your own.  You may delete it if you wish, but wholesale replacing the original text and title as you have done is not acceptable, especially after you already have answers.

Comment: I rolled it back AGAIN and flagged for repeated vandalism.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some solutions, starting from the most common that covers the most use cases, to the most narrow and specialized:

1. Compile all the files together into one program.
2. Use a scripting language instead of C.
3. Compile each program separately and use `system` to have one program execute another.
4. Compile each program except the main one into a shared object file. Have the main program `dlopen` the appropriate shared object and call a "start" function in it.
5. Have your main program launch the compiler to compile the applicable C code into a temporary execute, launch that executable (probably using `system`) and then delete it when it's done.

Comment: @CarsonMarsin Compile each C file into a separate program. Then you can use `system` to have one program launch another. Another option is to use one of the `exec` family of functions to have one program be replaced by another. For example, if you compiled `foo.c` into `foo`, you can use `system("./foo");` to launch it.

Comment: yes i understand david . But how to exactly use system . any guide tutorial ? i tried to search in google i couldn't find even a written guide

Comment: You just pass the full path of the executable to the `system` function. [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/system-call-in-c/) is an example of a program that uses `system` to compile and run another program.

Comment: Sorry. Is it not obvious what it's doing anyway?

Comment: to be honest no , i want a detailed thing @david :p (first year in C that's why)

Answer (score 0):

Basic Example of working with the Multiple Files:

**file1.c**

```
void func1()
{
    printf("from func1\n");
}
```

**file2.c**

```
void func2()
{
    printf("from func2\n");
}
```

similarly write **file3.c**, **file4.c** ... **fileN.c** and `func3()` to `func4()` ... `funcN()`

As we have spread our entire program across multiple files, symbols in one **`.c`** file cannot be known to other **`.c`** file, as a result when we compile our program
we will see some warning/errors.

**Use of `extern` keyword**
`extern` is a [storage class](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_storage_classes.htm#:%7E:text=The%20extern%20storage%20class%20is,that%20has%20been%20previously%20defined.)

`extern` keyword is to declare the symbols which are defined in other source files.

Though we can directly use `extern` to declare symbols in other source files, the best practice is to create a header file(probably same name as that of source file with **`.h`** extension) and give the declarations there.

For all of our **`.c`** files we have created (except main.c) we need to create a **`.h`** file and add the function declaration there.

Ex:
**file1.h** will have  `extern void func1();`
and
**file2.h** will have  `extern void func2();` and so on so forth..

Note: functions by default will have `extern` storage class, generally ignored if called in same file where defined.

**main.c**

```
/* standard header files */
#include <stdio.h>
/* user defined header files */
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

/** add other header files here **/

int main()
{
    int ch;
    printf("enter choice (1-5):");
    scanf("%d", &ch);
    if(ch == 1)
        func1();
    else if(ch == 2)
        func2();
    else if(ch == 3)
        func3();
    else if(ch == 4)
        func4();
    else if(ch == 5)
        func5();
    else
        printf("invalied choice\n");
    return 0;
}
```

**Compiling multiple files**

```
gcc -Wall main.c file1.c file2.c file3.c file4.c file5.c -o test

./test
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but though yiur solution makes sense (instead of compiling different programs) you forgot to mention the need to define a set of `fileN.h` files in which to declare the `funcN ()` prototypes. Or at least to suggest the use of the extern keyword

Comment: @Roberto Caboni, Thanks anyway, I left that on purpose adding a **NOTE** indicating need to fix warnings, since there is no use of external variables here, dint suggest `extern`

Comment: `extern` keyword tells the compiler that some variables issued by the current compilation unit are defined in a different compilation unit. But the same is true in case of external functions (in your case you `funcN ()`)