# bpf_prog_test_run() causes unexpected packet data

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf, xdp-bpf

---

I try to perform a test run for an XDP BPF program. The BPF program uses the `bpf_xdp_adjust_meta()` helper, to adjust the meta data.

##### I tried:

1. to run `bpf_prog_test_run()`
2. to run `bpf_prog_test_run_xattr()`

**1. `bpf_prog_test_run()`** 
(The first time I tried my bpf program's debug messages told me that adjusting the data_meta field failed.) Now it can adjust the data_meta, but the `iph.ihl` field is apparently not set to 5.

**2. `bpf_prog_test_xattr()`** 
This always returns -1, so something failed.

##### The Code

**packet:**

```c
struct ipv4_packet pkt_v4 = {
    .eth.h_proto = __bpf_constant_htons(ETH_P_IP),
    .iph.ihl = 5,
    .iph.daddr = __bpf_constant_htonl(33554442),
    .iph.saddr = __bpf_constant_htonl(50331658),
    .iph.protocol = IPPROTO_TCP,
    .iph.tot_len = __bpf_constant_htons(MAGIC_BYTES),
    .tcp.urg_ptr = 123,
    .tcp.doff = 5,
};
```

**test attribute:**

```c
__u32 size, retval, duration;
char data_out[128];
struct xdp_md ctx_in, ctx_out;
```

```c
struct bpf_prog_test_run_attr test_attr = {
    .prog_fd        = prog_fd,
    .repeat         = 100,
    .data_in        = &pkt_v4,
    .data_size_in   = sizeof(&pkt_v4),
    .data_out       = &data_out,
    .data_size_out  = sizeof(data_out),
    .ctx_in         = &ctx_in,
    .ctx_size_in    = sizeof(ctx_in),
    .ctx_out        = &ctx_out,
    .ctx_size_out   = sizeof(ctx_out),
    .retval         = &retval,
    .duration       = &duration,
};
```

**test execution:** 
`bpf_prog_test_run(main_prog_fd, 1, &pkt_v4, sizeof(pkt_v4), &data_out, &size, &retval, &duration)` -> `iph.ihl` field is 0.

`bpf_prog_test_run_xattr(&test_attr)` -> returns -1.

##### Note

The program was already successfully attached to the hook point of a real network interface and ran as intended. I just replaced the code that attaches the program to the hook point with the above code for testing.

Comment: I changed the title and deleted the old question since it based on false assumptions and the actual problem was something else

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The `struct ipv4_packet pkt_v4` was not `packed`.**

When I replace `__packed` with `__attribute__ ((__packed__))` it works.

For information what happens without packing, see for example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5473189/what-is-a-packed-structure-in-c).
Basically the compiler adds **padding bytes** which leads to the fields in the packet being in different places than expected.